# Unix Cronjob | Not getting emails

Tags: unix, cron

I have one cronjob in which I have below command.
mailto=abc@xyz.com

But I am not receiving any email?
I have installed postfix also but still not receiving emails.

Is there any other software I need to install?
I want to send confirmation email on above id once cron job is finished.

Comment: Try adding `>> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1` at then end of cronjob command. This will log any error occurred during executing in `/tmp/log.txt` log file. This will help in further debugging

Comment: Thanks Vikas. I have am already getting logs for cron but the only thing is that I am NOT receiving email. I have a requirement like "If cronjob fails or success; it should notify to user with an email" . Can you guide on this how should I do this?

Comment: You can try two things to debug this issue 1) Change `mailto` to `MAILTO` 2) Try sending test mail from command prompt to check if its working from command line or not `echo Test | mail -s Test abc@xyz.com`. If this command does not work from command line then there is something wrong with smtp configuration.